# Generated $\sigma$-algebras identity (unions)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove
$$\sigma (\mathcal{C}_1 \cup \mathcal{C}_2) = \sigma (\sigma( \mathcal{C}_1 ) \cup \sigma (\mathcal{C}_2))$$
for non-empty $\mathcal{C}_1,\mathcal{C}_2 \in \mathscr{P}(\Omega)$.
So I know that $\mathcal{C}_1 \cup \mathcal{C}_2 \subseteq \sigma( \mathcal{C}_1 ) \cup \sigma (\mathcal{C}_2)$ and therefore
$$\sigma (\mathcal{C}_1 \cup \mathcal{C}_2) \subseteq \sigma (\sigma( \mathcal{C}_1 ) \cup \sigma (\mathcal{C}_2)),$$
But I still don't know why the other contention is true.
As always, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the fact that, if $\mathcal  A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then the $\sigma$-algebra it generates is itself: $\sigma(\mathcal A)=\mathcal A$.  We'll also need monotonicity: If $\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal D$ then $\sigma(\mathcal C)\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal D)$.  Armed with these observations, we can proceed as follows.

Since $\mathcal C_1\subseteq\mathcal C_1\cup\mathcal C_2$, we have $\sigma(\mathcal C_1)\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal C_1\cup\mathcal C_2)$, and similarly $\sigma(\mathcal C_2)\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal C_1\cup\mathcal C_2)$. So $\sigma(\mathcal C_1)\cup\sigma(\mathcal C_2)\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal C_1\cup\mathcal C_2)$. By monotonicity, we get $\sigma(\sigma(\mathcal C_1)\cup\sigma(\mathcal C_2))\subseteq\sigma(\sigma(\mathcal C_1\cup\mathcal C_2))$. Finally, our initial observation simplifies the right side of this to just $\sigma(\mathcal C_1\cup\mathcal C_2)$, as required.